# NoReverseMatch at /post/

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I want to create a comment part. I did but there is an error in my detail page. The error is

*NoReverseMatch at /post/123/

Reverse for 'blog_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P\d+)/comment/$']*

**Here is my codes.**

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

class BlogComment(models.Model):

    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter comment about blog here.")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["post_date"]

    def __str__(self):
        len_title = 75
        if len(self.description) > len_title:
            titlestring = self.description[:len_title] + '...'
        else:
            titlestring = self.description
        return titlestring
```

**views.py**

```
class BlogCommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = BlogComment
    fields = ['description', ]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):


        context = super(BlogCommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['blog'] = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):


        form.instance.author = self.request.user

        form.instance.blog = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

        return super(BlogCommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk'], })
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.BlogCommentCreate.as_view, name='blog_comment'),
```

**postcomment_form.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>Post your comment for: <a href="{% url 'post_detail' Post.pk %}">{{post.name}}</a></p>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**post_detail.html**

```
</div>
<div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
    <h4>Comments</h4>

    {% for comment in blog.blogcomment_set.all %}
        <hr>
        <p>{{ comment.author }} ({{ comment.post_date }}) - {{ comment.description }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <hr>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'blog_comment' blog.id %}">Add a new comment</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a> to add a new comment</p>
    {% endif %}


</div>
```

I am sorry for a lot of code. But I cannot understand the problem that I made and I need help. Thanks a lot for your helps.

Comment: Please show the PostDetail view.